# ARIA attributes for a website about a video game?

Tags: seo, accessibility

I'm creating an interactive community website for a **video game** - a first person shooter. People can share *ideas* with others - these ideas basically consists out of images. The very rough explanation.

Should I still use ARIA attributes? At the moment, my main concern is SEO.
If I understand correctly ARIA attributes are used to help people with disadvantages, for example people who are blind or can't barely see anything and use the internet with screen readers.

Since my website is all around a video game, I feel like it would be useless to implement ARIA attributes.

Comment: Are you referring to ARIA attributes in relation to your application or website??

Comment: @closetnoc Sorry? I'm not sure what your question is about exactly

Comment: Is this question about your application or website??

Comment: @closetnoc with app I meant my website, sorry for the confusin. Will update the question

Comment: Okay. I do not have any expertise with ARIA, however, I have never seen anything about it and SEO so in that respect, I am sure there is not a problem. As well, SEO is not about mark-up as it is about content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAI-ARIA are attributes that can make your Web site/app (more) accessible.

This has nothing to do with SEO¹.

If you use HTML5, you are already using WAI-ARIA, as many elements come with *default implicit ARIA semantics* ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26952106/1591669)).
You should add WAI-ARIA attributes if you are re-purposing an element, or if you can’t use an appropriate semantic element, or if you have to change the native semantics, or if you create your own interactive widget, etc.

If you wonder if you should care about accessibility for a video game: Yes, you should (hint: people with disabilities like to play games, too). To what extent depends on the kind of game, your budget, your audience, etc.

¹ That doesn’t necessarily mean that all search engines would ignore WAI-ARIA; it’s not inconceivable that they could be used as signals by search engines.